# No latest version available for Spring-webflow-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar after 2018

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, tomcat10, jakarta-migration

can someone or Spring team please tell me if there is any latest version of Spring-webflow-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar which supports Tomcat 10 migration. Currently, this spring-webflow jar have references of javax.servlet.* whereas Tomcat 10 migration expects references of jakarta.servlet.*. in this dependent jar.

My expectation is, to upgrade my application from Spring 5.x to spring 6.x with Tomcat 10 and JDK17. My Application has both webflows and WEBMVC flows. I don't have problems with WEBMVC flows but there were problems with WEBFLOWS because of "Spring-webflow-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar". This jar has some classes with "javax.servlet.*" imports so when i try to upgrade from Tomcat 9 to Tomcat10, it expects "jakarta.servlet.*"

Comment: Finally Spring Webflow 3.x is released so that we can migrate to java 17